# jQuery set class not working after its already been set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

trying to make a simple expanding heading script.

I don't wish to use accordions and just looking for a light weight home made solution. As i enjoy writing and learning things myself.

In my eyes, what i have should work. But it doesnt.

The aim is:

When a heading is clicked, all of the content is hidden and then the next content element after the heading is shown. This prevents more than one content being shown at any time.

After this, the div class gets changed to be a 'selected' state.

This works okay.

However, the next part runs if the heading class is the selected state, and if so it SHOULD change its class back to the normal and also hide the next element content.

The aim is to allow the hide / show options.

The latter part of changing back the class doesnt work however. I also know there is a much for efficient way of writing this, but not sure how.

JS:

```
$(function() {
$('.headingHelp').click(function(){
    $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
    $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp_sel');
});

$('.headingHelp_sel').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp');
});
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<p class="headingHelp">Content Heading</p>
<div class="infoHelp">
Content 
</div>

<p class="headingHelp">Content Heading 2</p>
<div class="infoHelp">
Content 2
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7bHn/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your "selected" class is added after the DOM is loaded, jQuery is not aware of it.

I suggest using jQuery's `on()` for [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). This will allow you to select dynamically generated classes:

```
$(document).on('click','.headingHelp',function(){
    $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
    $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp_sel');
});

$(document).on('click','.headingHelp_sel',function(){
    $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp');
});
```

[Working Example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/C7bHn/2/)

### Edit:

Here's another method without using delegation. It just adds/removes a "sel" class rather than changing the class completely.

```
$('.headingHelp').click(function(){

    // save clicked element in a variable for use below
    $this=$(this);  

    // remove / add "selected" class
    $('.headingHelp').removeClass('sel');
    $this.addClass('sel');

    // fade in / out content
    $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $this.next('.infoHelp').stop().fadeIn();

});
```

```
.infoHelp {
    display: none;
}

.headingHelp {
    background-color:#999;
    padding: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

.headingHelp:hover,
.headingHelp.sel {
    background-color:#666;
}
```

[Working Example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/C7bHn/10/)

Comment: Didnt think about using .on() Silly me! Thanks thought shall mark as correct when i can :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector working "AT CURRENT MOMENT" . Your selector $('.headingHelp_sel') empty when running this code.

Best code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.headingHelp').click(function(){
        var open = $(this).next('.infoHelp').is(':visible');
        $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();

        if(!open)
        {
            $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
        }
    }); 
});
```